# How do i call a php script from a c program using system()?

Tags: php, c, system

I am writing a c program that will call a php script every few seconds in the background. So when you first call this program, it will  create a child process through fork, and then exit the parent process, while the child process will be in an infinite loop. So far inside that infinte loop, I have the line `system("echo hello >> daemon.txt")` inside hte while loop, and it updates accordingly, so I know that the process is working. However when I call my script, it seems like it does not execute.

My php script timeChecker.php

`#!/usr/bin/php
    <?php 
        $handle =fopen("hello","a");
        fwrite($handle, "boo\n");
        fclose($handle);
    ?>`

When called from commandline using either php timeChecker.php or ./timeChecker.php, the code executes as it should.

However, after trying multiple methods of calling the command such as `system("php timeChecker.php")`, `system("/usr/bin/php timeChecker.php")`, `system("/usr/bin/php var/www/timeChecker.php")`, `system("/var/www/timeChecker.php")` and all variations of that, the code still does not execute. Is there something simple that I am doing wrong? Or should I simply use a different method of checking the script?

Comment: if you can write C why would you call a PHP script every few seconds- why not use C?

Comment: Just set php binary path as PATH environmental variable in your OS

Comment: Dagon-The application is already written exclusively in php. Essentially all the C program does is create a process that will check databases and do some actions every few minutes.
AJeneral - Php is in my path variable already(using linux). I used the full path to php just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are suggesting in your question, the php script is in "/var/www".
Do you have the privileges to execute in that directory?

test is the c program calling the script through system().
I've made it work this way:

```
    sudo mkdir /var/www/script_dir
    sudo mv timeChecker.php /var/www/script_dir
    sudo mv test /var/www/script_dir
    sudo chown -R myusername:myusername /var/www/script_dir
```

Execute test from the script_dir.

Comment: While there was no permissions issue, you helped me realize it was a directory issue: inside the php script, the "hello" file was created in the root directory rather than the directory with the script. Essentially, always use absolute paths. Stupid mistake on my part, but thank you for your help